# Clear VertScrollBox in firemonkey application

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

I have a  firemonkey app for android mobile, in XE7, Win8. I have the procedure ShowMsg, below, to show messages into a VertScrollBox.

I´d like to clear the VertScrollBox and I am trying use the ClearVertScrollBox procedure to do it, but I have had no success.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
procedure TForm1.ClearVertScrollBox;
var i:integer;
begin
  for i:=VSB.ControlsCount-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    if (VSB.Controls[i] is TCalloutRectangle) then begin
      VSB.Controls[i].DisposeOf;
      VSB.Controls[i]:=nil;
    end;
  end;
  VSB.Repaint;
end;

var VSB: TVertScrollBox;

procedure TForm1.ShowMsg(Title,GCMMsg,Msg:string);
var
  CR: TCalloutRectangle;
  L: TText;
begin
  CR := TCalloutRectangle.Create(Self);
  CR.Parent := VSB;
  CR.Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
  CR.CalloutPosition := TCalloutPosition.cpLeft;
  CR.Margins.Top := 10;
  CR.Margins.Bottom := 10;
  CR.Margins.Right := 5;
  CR.Height := 75;

  L := TText.Create(Self);
  L.Parent := CR;
  L.Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
  L.Text := Title;
  L.Margins.Left := 15;
  L.Margins.Right := 5;
  L.Width := CR.Width-20;
  L.Height:=20;

  L := TText.Create(Self);
  L.Parent := CR;
  L.Align := TAlignLayout.alClient;
  L.Text := GCMMsg;//GCMMsg+':'+Msg;
  L.Margins.Left := 15;
  L.Margins.Right := 5;
  L.Width := CR.Width-20;

  L.WordWrap := True;
  L.AutoSize := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ClearVertScrollBox` just needs some adjusting, you are simply going through its controls and checking if one of them is a `TCalloutRectangle` but the `TVertScrollBox` does not simply store your `TCalloutRectangle` in the first tree of control nodes.

`TVertScrollBox` has a `TScrollContent` which would be the control in which your controls are stored

So something like this would suffice

```
var
    I,II : Integer; 
begin
for i:= VSB.ControlsCount-1 downto 0 do
    begin
        if VSB.Controls[I].ClassType = TScrollContent then
        begin
            for II := VSB.Controls[I].ControlsCount-1 downto 0 do
            begin
                if VSB.Controls[I].Controls[II].ClassType = TCalloutRectangle then
                begin
                    VSB.Controls[I].Controls[II].Parent := nil;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end; 
end;
```

You are also creating memory leaks in your creation of your `TCalloutRectangle`

You are creating all your objects with owners, and more specifically with the `Self` keyword you are setting the Form as the owner, and thus even if you  "visually" remove it from the `TVertScrollBox` the object is still owned by your form, and the objects reference count will never reach 0 meaning [ARC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers/%22ARC%22) will not be able to Free it.

Instead of creating your objects with owners like this :

`CR := TCalloutRectangle.Create(Self);`

Do this

`CR := TCalloutRectangle.Create(nil);`

If you are already assigning it to a parent you do not need to assign it to a owner as well, do this for your `TCalloutRectangle` and `TText` (which I am assuming are TLabels?) objects

if you create your objects only with parents and use the new code to remove them from the `TVertScrollBox` you will break all references to those objects and they are freed, which means no need for that `DisposeOf` call

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below to clear my scroll boxes, in my case I just want to delete all the items of the list, not a specific one.

```
unit uScrollBoxHelper;

interface

uses FMX.Layouts;

type
  TVertScrollBoxHelper = class helper for TVertScrollBox
  public
    procedure Clear;
  end;

  THorzScrollBoxHelper = class helper for THorzScrollBox
  public
    procedure Clear;
  end;

implementation

{ TVertScrollBoxHelper }

procedure TVertScrollBoxHelper.Clear;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := self.Content.ChildrenCount - 1 downto 0 do
    self.Content.Children.Items[I].DisposeOf;
end;

{ THorzScrollBoxHelper }

procedure THorzScrollBoxHelper.Clear;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := self.Content.ChildrenCount - 1 downto 0 do
    self.Content.Children.Items[I].DisposeOf;
end;

end.
```

Then when I wanna use the code in my forms I simply do:

```
  VertScrollBox1.BeginUpdate;
  VertScrollBox1.Clear;
...
  VertScrollBox1.EndUpdate;
```